# GGplot2 with subcategory

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a histogram with error bars. Something similar to [this](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Plotting_means_and_error_bars_(ggplot2)/figure/unnamed-chunk-15-1.png).

But my data has multiple categories and subcategories. Each subcategory has 2 values that need to be plotted. I figured a way out to plot the error bars. but What I'm missing is how to plot two bars.

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(ggplot2)
library(grid)

## create some data with asymmetric fill aes to generalize solution 
data <- read.table(text = "Group Category Value Value2
                   AD-0 CF 15  10
                   AR-0 CF 12  10
                   C S3   87    1", 
                   header=TRUE)

# user-level interface 
axis.groups = function(groups) {
  structure(
    list(groups=groups),
    ## inheritance since it should be a element_text
    class = c("element_custom","element_blank")  
  )
}
# returns a gTree with two children: 
# the categories axis
# the groups axis
element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, x,...)  {
  cat <- list(...)[[1]]
  groups <- element$group
  ll <- by(data$Group,data$Category,I)
  tt <- as.numeric(x)

  grbs <- Map(function(z,t){
    labs <- ll[[z]]
    vp = viewport(
             x = unit(t,'native'), 
             height=unit(2,'line'),
             width=unit(diff(tt)[1],'native'),
             xscale=c(0,length(labs)))
    grid.rect(vp=vp)
    textGrob(labs,x= unit(seq_along(labs)-0.5,
                                'native'),
             y=unit(2,'line'),
             vp=vp)
  },cat,tt)

  g.X <- textGrob(cat, x=x)
  gTree(children=gList(do.call(gList,grbs),g.X), cl = "custom_axis")
}

## # gTrees don't know their size 
grobHeight.custom_axis = 
  heightDetails.custom_axis = function(x, ...)
  unit(3, "lines")

## the final plot call
ggplot(data=data, aes(x=Category, y=Value2, fill=Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(width=0.9),stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=paste(Value2, "%")),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)+
  theme(axis.text.x = axis.groups(unique(data$Group)),
        legend.position="none")
```

Doing the final plot call twice will not do the job because you are rewriting the data. I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in R.

I'm newbie to R. I know in python that you can plot it by using the same axis and calculating the distance from the current bar.

```
rects1 = ax.bar(ind, AE1, width,
            color='0.2',
            error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='red'),
            label='Pow')

rects2 = ax.bar(ind+width, AE2, width,
                color='0.5',
                error_kw=dict(elinewidth=2,ecolor='black'),
                label='Perf')
```

Is there something like that in `R`?

Comment: Not sure what you want. But for errobars stratified by group you simply add: `geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Value2+5,ymin=Value2-5),width=0.2,position =position_dodge(width=0.9))` Replace the 5 with a number you need.

Comment: I want something like [link] (http://i.stack.imgur.com/D60lu.png). but with two values instead of one. The first answer provides me that. but, I am unable to have AD-0 and AR-0 in the same category.

Comment: Probably my above comment isn't clear enough. by `value` i mean the number of parameters for a group in a category

Answer (score 0):

this could help you

you need first to convert from wide  to long

```
library(reshape2)
data_long <- melt(data, id.vars=c("Group", "Category"))
```

and then plot

```
ggplot(data=data_long, aes(x=Group, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge",stat='identity')
```

is this what you want?

Comment: No, in this scenario, `groups` don't show up on the chart; moreover, if a `category` consists of more than two groups. only the first group is shown. in this case, it is `AD-0`.

Comment: Thanks for the change. Now, the category for a given group isn't shown. :(

Comment: Create an interaction between the factors Group and variable
`ggplot(data=data_long, aes(x=Category, y=value, fill=Group:variable))+geom_bar(position="dodge",stat='identity')+
theme(axis.text.x = axis.groups(unique(data$Group)),
      legend.position="none")+
geom_text(aes(x=Category, y=value,label=paste(value, "%")),
          position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25)`

Comment: @Jimbou: thanks for that. I'm trying to get the legend working. i am not able to distinguish between Value and Value2